# Prove that in an acute triangle a line drawn through $A$ and the circumcenter is perpendicular to the reflection of $BC$ on the angle bisector of $A$

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

Here is a picture provided:

[image]

The angle shown here is what we need to prove.

This is where I got: suppose $BAC$ angle is $a$; $ABC$ is $b$; and $BCA$ is $c$. $BC$ and $B'C'$ intersect at $K$.

Then $AC'B'=c$ and $C'B'A=b$

$CKB'=b-c$

and I couldn't get any further. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this theorem works on obtuse triangles. That is if I drew the drawing incorrectly since the picture is blocked on my computer

Comment: thanks. I forgot about obtuse triangles, but fixed the question.

Comment: You can first prove that the reflected line is tangent at $A$. Since any tangent is perpendicular to a circle's radius, you can end your proof there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $O$ be the circumcentre. $\angle COA=2\angle B$ and $\triangle AOC$ is isosceles, so $\angle OAC=90^\circ-\angle B$.

Combined with $\angle AB'C'=\angle CBA=\angle B$ we get the result.

Comment: This is correct in the case $\angle B<90^{\circ}$. We have to consider the other two cases for a full solution.

Comment: @bjorn93 true, or you could just use directed angles.

Comment: @jlammy this theorem only works for angles less than 90.